# Google Apps Script. Make script work in active row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I use simple table to register tasks which I should do for my clients. Every time when I reached task, I send it in history cell with information about adding date.
Now I need to automate this process and have a script:

```
function goal (){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),"GMT+5", "dd.MM.YY..HH:mm");
var num1 = ss.getRange("B7").getValue();
var num2 = ss.getRange("C7").getValue();
var num3 = ss.getRange("D7").getValue();
ss.getRange("D7").setValue(num3+" / "+num1+" "+num2);
ss.getRange("B7").clear();
ss.getRange("C7").setValue(formattedDate);
var range = ss.getRange("B7");
ss.setActiveRange(range);
}
```

A7 - name of client

B7 - Active task

C7 - Date of creating task

D7 - History of all tasks

And here is the question:

Now script work only in one row range, how I can make it work in active row range?

Comment: For this you could use getActiveCell(): https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getActiveCell() to get the active cell on the sheet which returns a range and then getRow() method to get the row value of that range object. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function goal (){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),"GMT+5", "dd.MM.YY..HH:mm");
  var row = ss.getActiveCell().getRow();
  var r = ss.getRange(row, 2, 1, 3);
  var rValues = r.getValues();
  r.setValues([["", formattedDate, rValues[0][2] +" / "+rValues[0][0]+" "+rValues[0][1]]]);
  ss.setActiveRange(ss.getRange(row, 2));
}
```